# Ubuntu 16 upgrade results incredibly slow wifi

Tags: performance, ubuntu, wifi, ubuntu-16.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu16 from 14. Everything went fine, however my wifi connection went to a crawl. I actually experienced this on a previous system that I installed Ubuntu16 on and because of that, stuck with Ubuntu14 for as long as I could until version lag forced me to upgrade.

I came across this solution that was referring to Ubuntu 17

https://askubuntu.com/questions/905288/extremely-slow-connection-after-17-04-update

And it seemed to do the trick!

The only issue is that now after a system suspend or boot-up, I have to run

```
    sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Otherwise I cannot connect to any server.

Its not a huge deal, I've aliased it at this point, but it would be nice get it operating appropriately.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [this link](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex). If the download by the first link failed, download [this file](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).
2. Open the Terminal and run these commands on your ubuntu pc.

   ```
   cd rtlwifi_new-master
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
   sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
   sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up
   sudo iw dev wlp13s0 scan
   ```